# Grep to match specific times

Tags: regex, grep

I've got a `file.txt` with lines in the format `HH:MM:SS`:

```
00:05:50
01:40:10
00:23:09
00:34:02
```

And I want to print out the lines which show a **time between 30 minutes and 1 hour and 20 minutes**.

This is my attempt:

```
LINES=`grep '(00:[3-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|01:[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|01:20:00)' file.txt`
echo "$LINES"
```

However, this shows no result. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your search might work if you add `-E` after `grep`

Answer (score 2):

Another option, using `awk`:

```
LINES=`awk '{ if ( $0 >= "00:30:00" && $0 <= "01:20:00") print $0 }' file.txt`
```

This works since 24-hour times in fixed format also follow lexical order in ASCII.

Or shorter, as @Kent generously suggested:

```
LINES=`awk '$0 >= "00:30:00" && $0 <= "01:20:00"' file.txt`
```

Comment: +1 regex is not the right tool for this kind of problem. the awk line could be written as `awk '$0>="00:30:00" && $0<="01:20:00"' file`

Comment: @Kent yep, thanks I just caught that! Thanks again. And thanks for the editorial clean-up. :)

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
   LINES=`egrep  '(00:[3-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])|(01:[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|01:20:00)' file.txt`
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why you wrote something like `(X)|(Y|Z)` instead of `(X|Y|Z)`?

Comment: `()` separates the patterns for `egrep`

Answer (score 0):

Another [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) option. Convert file contents into minutes and compare line-by-line with bounds supplied in minute units

```
awk -F: -v ll=30 -v ul=80 '{minutes=60*$1 + $2 + $3/60}; 
     minutes >= ll && minutes <= ul' file.txt
```